# Ubuntu 16.04 Live Installation Disk Puts Computer to Sleep

Tags: system-installation

I recently purchased a DELL Inspiron 15 3000 Series laptop.  I created an Ubuntu 16.04 Live Installation DVD. However, when I attempt to create a dual boot of Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10, the Ubuntu Live Installation DVD puts the laptop into "sleep" mode and it never wakes up to allow me to complete the installation of Ubuntu.

After I boot from the Ubuntu Live installation disk, I see the Ubuntu loading screen with the 4 dots under the logo, but from there my monitor shuts off.  I can hear the hard disk still working.  I tried leaving the machine alone for hours in case my processor is just slow (only 1.6 ghz intel pentium), but that doesn't help, the machine never comes out of sleep mode to allow me to install Ubuntu.  I even verified the integrity of the Ubuntu Live Installation disk by booting from it in my old laptop and it worked perfectly.  I believe that there may be some type of driver conflict that will not allow me to finish installation... any ideas?  Big Ubuntu fan... why can't install it?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `nomodeset` parameter? You could also try removing `quiet splash` so you can see what it's doing behind the scenes.

Comment: Your suggestion is a bit above my head...  I don't know how to do either of your recommended actions

Comment: Search for either of those. They have been explained many times on AskUbuntu.

Comment: thanks for the tip...found a [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076)